# Does IronPython support metaclasses?

Tags: python, ironpython, metaclass

Are Python metaclasses, and class factories fully supported by IronPython? If I have a functional code (in CPython 2.7) full with these thing will just work in IronPython?

Comment: Have you tried it?  In theory it should work since ironpython implements the full python specification.

Comment: Nope. Probably some basic examples will work, and my code is not finished yet so i don't really have what to try. Another thing is, i'm not sure, i have to use it like this, only a want to know, if there is a chance to go something wrong. Some exception, bugs, etc.

Comment: You don't have to try your finished code to determine if it support metaclasses. Just make up a simple test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is to simply try it.  IronPython and CPython are created differently, and have different optimisations.  Basic things like metaclasses should work without problems, but there might be other problems.  If you are trying to write code which supports both CPython and IronPython, then you should test it on both platforms as you go.  I.e., when you run your test suite, run it in both environments (and any others you intend to support).  I'm not sure if [tox](http://tox.testrun.org/latest/) supports IronPython, but it might help you set this up.